# Dual boot Win7/Ubuntu - GRUB menu flashes; cannot select

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on two separate partitions on my desktop. I used to be able to get the GRUB menu at startup when I had an older Ubuntu version (probably 10.x) but, after upgrading to 12.04 LTS, the menu just flashes for a fraction of a second, giving me no chance to make a selection. I have run boot-repair, tried holding down the SHIFT key, and a number of other solutions described on this forum. Nothing seems to work.

Here is the log from my boot-repair session: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5968366. I really hope that some Ubuntu expert can figure out what's wrong. Really appreciate the help/

Thanks...
- Ajoy

Comment: I do not see anything wrong. You have two systems so menu  should show by default. And you have the default 10 sec timeout still set. Does Ubuntu still boot fully? If you press down arrow key right after BIOS 5  or 6 times does Windows boot, (you do not want 4 as that will give recovery mode which may cause more issues).

Comment: I see some suspicious lines: For example, line numbers 355-356 say: "Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary. DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently."

Comment: Also, lines 420-426.

Comment: @oldfred And lines 460 and 479 say: "Error: Can't have a partition outside the disk!"

Comment: I have this exact problem. Win7/12.04.

Comment: Hi Tamlyn... Unfortunately, I do not have a solution. Actually, due to another issue, I had to reformat the hard drive and install Windows 8 on it. After that, I haven't yet tried to install Ubuntu on a separate partition yet. When I do that, I might (but hopefully, might not) run into the same issue again.